# "StartAfter" parameter equivalent in Google Cloud Storage in listing objects

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm quite new to GCP, and now struggling to list out files after a given key.

In AWS, we can provide an additional parameter `StartAfter` to the `list_objects_v2()` boto3 call for S3 client. Then, it will start providing files starting from that particular key.

```
kwargs["StartAfter"] = start_after_file
response = self._storage_client.list_objects_v2(
                    Bucket=self._bucket_name,
                    Prefix=prefix,
                    **kwargs
                )
```

I need to do the same in GCP, using the Google Cloud Storage (in Python). I'm going to use `list_blobs()` in Storage Client class, but I can't find any way to do this.

`prefix` parameter won't help since it will only return the files with that prefix.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/storage/buckets.html) for this library, there is no method to achieve this directly, you would need to filter the response in your code.

Nevertheless, you can open a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for this to be revised, or you can contact the team responsible for the library over at [their GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues)

Hope you find this useful.